# How to show page loading between pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am not sure if all Rails app behave the same or is it just within my app's setting. For my app when a page is loading (So the moment when a link is clicked until the content is responded from the server) there is no indication of page loading at all. In general website during the page load there would be a spinning wheel in the place of the favicon to show that the page is loading. I am using **Rails 4.0.0** on **Heroku**.

Comment: Not all browsers exhibit the same page loading indicators. Recent versions of Safari fill the address bar background color, Chrome (v43) animates the *tab* favicon (not the address bar favicon), etc. If pages are loading correctly it's unlikely to be a Rails issue and closer to a "browser UX" difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails uses turbolinks by default.

Please take a look at turbolinks and how it works. It basically replace the body of the page instead of making a new request, that's why you don't see the loading indication in the browser.

If you want to see your page loading you can either disable turbolinks, removing it from application.js, or use a gem like this one: https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails to show the actual loading of the page.

I strongly suggest you to keep turbolinks and go with the second option I gave you.

Comment: Hi @coorasse, thank you for taking the time to understand my question and provide such comprehensive answer! The second option is to provide some JS loading effect which give you the power of manipulating what loading looks like. However, is there a way to simply let the browser to behave just like a normal website (In Chrome would be loading message at lower left and spinning wheels in favicon)?

Comment: You have to remove turbolinks in order to go back to the standard behaviour

Answer (score 13):

From [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events), something like?

```js
$(document).on('page:fetch', function() {
  // show spinner
});

$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  // hide spinner
});
```

**Update for Turbolinks 5**

For [Turbolinks 5](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events):

```js
$document.on('turbolinks:click', function() {
  // show spinner
});

$document.on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // hide spinner
});
```

If you are using jQuery and your spinner is in the `div.spinner`, you can show and hide it with:

```js
$(document).on("turbolinks:click", function(){
  $(".spinner").show();
});

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
  $(".spinner").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those sites are what we call Single Page Applications most of the time. Those sites use a lot of AJAX based content fetching mechanism, and this thing has to do with front-end programming and a little with back-end programming.

If you really want to achieve this functionality, you can use AngularJS, BackboneJS and like other framework who support Single Page Web Applications.

When you fetch another page form server, all of your HTML, CSS, and JS is gone, and the new content is fetched and rendered. So there is no way that you can show a loading-page in between unless you use AJAX based pages.

Comment: He has exactly the opposite problem.